# Often mouse stutter on windows 10

Tags: performance, mouse, freeze, windows-10

I have a really annoying issue where windows 10 freezes/stutters almost every second for a small period of time. It's best noticeable when I move my mouse around in circles. As the mouse moves, every second or so, the mouse will freeze, and then almost immediately jump to where it's supposed to be in less than half a second. It's also not just my mouse, as I have tried using my track pad, and other mice, and all have the same issue. It's also noticeable when typing, where I type a character, and it doesn't respond for a bit and then the character will appear. Another symptom I've noticed, is I'll be scrolling through a web page, and the page will freeze for a split second, and my computer will beep at me, and then scroll like normal. Seems to happen more, the faster I scroll. It's a very minor stutter, but it happens often enough, where it just feels like my computer is running slow, or not optimally. What could be the cause of this? Drivers? Windows 10 itself?

Computer Spec: Acer Aspire R7, Recently updated from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10.

Comment: I have the exact same laptop with the exact same issue.